# Can I install Remix without using npx or npm?

Tags: remix.run

I don't have permission to use npx on the shared server I'm using. Can I manually install react and remix?
If it's possible, where can I find instructions to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can just install [`create-remix`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-remix) manually, then execute the cli directly.

```
$ npm install create-remix
```

```
$ ./node_modules/.bin/create-remix my-remix-project
```

Comment: I can't use npm. Not allowed on my server.

Comment: Ah, I thought you just meant npx. If you can't use npm then you're going to have a pretty horrid time working with Node.js. I've updated your question to make it clearer.